# Login by MySQL-LDAP-Thymeleaf with spring security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap, thymeleaf

it's my first time with spring and also with Ldap so I have several difficulty to make login for a web site. I read a lot of sample, guides and documents but now I'm confusing by the several type of implementation.
In the first time I have a login page where user puts own user name and password and I check into DB if the user and password are correct. If it's not I have to use Ldap to authenticate the user and add the data to database.
I'm finding the best way to do it, in my project I'm using Spring for REst webservice and for database, so i would like to use spring even to login with ldap. I found several document but all differet each other, some with xml files and some with class and annotations that I prefer. I have never used spring, ldap and login mechanism, is there an example of this?What do i have to do?
This is my project structure:

[image]

Any idea?Thanks

Until now I Make this project from zero and then, if it works, put it into my project:

```
package service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import dao.UserDao;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao UserDao;    

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        model.User domainUser = UserDao.getUser(login);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(
                domainUser.getLogin(), 
                domainUser.getPassword(), 
                enabled, 
                accountNonExpired, 
                credentialsNonExpired, 
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
        );
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
        } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

apllicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- Security (authentication and authorization) configuration -->
    <import resource="applicationContext-security.xml" />
</beans>
```

applicationContext-Security

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Authentication using a memory user list -->
        <beans:bean id='customUserDetailsService' class='com.service.CustomUserDetailsService'>
        </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Login pages -->
        <!-- <form-login login-page="/user-login.html" default-target-url="/success-login.html" authentication-failure-url="/error-login.html">
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.html">

        </logout></form-login></intercept-url></intercept-url></http> -->

        <form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/login-error.html" />
        <logout />
        <!-- Security zones -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/shared/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

springServlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <!-- Use spring servlet for all requests, including static resources -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>


    <!-- Use @MVC annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- User @Controller, @Service... annotations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />


    <!-- Thymeleaf template engine -->
    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <!-- Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want -->
        <!-- templates to be automatically updated when modified.        -->
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="stsm" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <!-- Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring MVC front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Error pages -->
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

UserDao

```
package dao;

import model.User;

public interface UserDao {
     public User getUser(String login);
}
```

UserDaoImpl

```
package dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import model.User;


@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public User getUser(String login) {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        Query query = openSession().createQuery("from User u where u.login = :login");
        query.setParameter("login", login);
        userList = query.list();
        if (userList.size() > 0)
            return userList.get(0);
        else
            return null;    
    }

}
```

HibernateConfiguration

```
   package com.configuration;

    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan({ "com" })
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
    public class HibernateConfiguration {

        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
            dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

            return dataSource;
        }

        private Properties hibProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
            properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
            return properties;
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }

            @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.websystique.spring.model" });
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
         }


    }
```

I have a problem with CustomUserDetailsService because model.User domainUser = UserDao.getUser(login); has UserDao null
Is It correct:

```
<!-- User @Controller, @Service... annotations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring boot the following class is sufficient to provide the Spring-Security LDAP based authentication:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
    } 

    @Configuration  
    protected static class AuthenticationConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
            LdapContextSource ctx = new LdapContextSource();
            try {
                ctx.setUrl("aaa");
                ctx.setBase("bbb");
                ctx.setUserDn("ccc");
                ctx.setPassword("ddd");
                ctx.setReferral("follow");
                ctx.afterPropertySet();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ctx;
        }

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationmanagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource(contextSource()).userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}");
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: @https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.java    the spring-security source code, following is the section where it authenticate the password with default salt provided:-                                                                                              if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(),
    presentedPassword, salt)) {
   logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");
...................
   }

Comment: i would like to test my code before change it but I have a problem with CustomUserDetailsService because model.User domainUser = UserDao.getUser(login); has UserDao null.
This code derive from an example on the web but the line <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="service.CustomUserDetailsService"></beans:bean>
 in aplicationCOntext-securety is added by me

Comment: Can you try this -> private UserDao userDao;   //camelCase variable name i.e. small U in the beginning.

Comment: I have already tried with both private UserDao userDao and UserDaoImpl usedDaoImpl. I think that the problem is the definition of bean into applicationContext-Security

Comment: Yes definition is the problem. I cant see userDao def in your xml so i beleive you have used annotation @Repository on the UserDaoImpl class. Pls confirm.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the class in the first post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89779/discussion-between-avis-and-luca).